# Server activate a new thread to process each incoming client request,

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having one to one server client application. I want to make use of multithreading so that server should activate a new thread to process each incoming client request,

Server :

```
public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(79)

         while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted an echo request");
            System.out.println("... local socket address " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
            System.out.println("... remote socket address " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            while (true) {
               int b = input.read();
               if (b == -1) break;
               output.write(b);
            }
        socket.close();
     }
  }
}
```

Client part :

```
public class EchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int b;      
    Socket socket = new Socket(args[0], 79);
    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("The socket is connected the server.");
    System.out.println("... local socket address is " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
    System.out.println("... remote socket address is " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    output.write(args[1].getBytes());
    socket.shutdownOutput();
    while (true) {
        b = input.read();
        if (b == -1) {
           break;
         }
         System.out.print((char) b);
      }
     System.out.println();
     socket.close();
   }
 }
```

What is best way to change server part to get multithreading. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an accepted connection you should pass the `Socket` to a new thread. An easy way is to use an `ExecutorService` for thread handling. Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Replace with suitable executor
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(79);

    while (true) {
        final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    handleSocket(socket);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Handle exception
                }

            }

            private void handleSocket(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
                // Do stuff with your socket, same as original code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @K Erlandsson What other solutions might you consider in order to increase throughput and reduce latency?

Comment: @ms8 I think this general solution will be good for most cases on most hardware. Improvements I would start with are using a fixed size thread pool to avoid an explosion of threads under high load and slow clients. I would also limit the request queue to the executor to fail fast and recover quickly if we can't keep up with the load. Number of threads and queue length would vary depending on client behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side of code should change so it will be able to run a new thread per socket which is accepted by server socket.
The server code can be like this:

```
public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(79);

        while (true) {
            final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Accepted an echo request");
                    System.out.println("... local socket address " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
                    System.out.println("... remote socket address " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                    try {
                        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                        while (true) {
                            int b = input.read();
                            if (b == -1) break;
                            output.write(b);
                        }
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: • What other solutions might you consider in order to increase throughput and reduce latency?

Comment: In more complicated matters you can use a thread pool for getting your thread instances.

Comment: It is like the answer that K Erlandsson has presented. *Executors* are sample of ThreadPools. It doesn't make any changes in your socket activity but as long as you want to make a thread per client you have to manage your threads some how.